# How is the team name order determined for House Quidditch games at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, quidditch

How is the team name order determined for the House Quidditch games at Hogwarts?

For example, in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* they announce a match as

> **Lee:** *Hello, and welcome to Hogwarts' first Quidditch game of the season! Today's game **Slytherin versus Gryffindor!!!***

where two Hogwarts teams are playing and Hogwarts is both teams' home stadium.

**Is there a rule that determines X vs. Y?**

Comment: I don't get the second half of your question. What does the fact that Slytherin and Gryffindor being both Hogwarts team come in the order of the game?

Comment: I think OP is saying that neither team has any kind of home advantage to determine the name order, because both teams use the same pitch and come from the same school.

Answer (score 5):

Of the seven house matches explicitly billed as "X versus Y" in the Harry Potter books, **every single example** has Gryffindor first, followed by whichever team Harry/Gryffindor is playing. This is the case when the narrator is talking as well as when people are talking to Harry.

> *"Gryffindor versus Slytherin"* - Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
> *"Gryffindor versus Ravenclaw"* - Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
> *"Gryffindor versus Ravenclaw"* - Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (mentioned twice)
> *"Gryffindor versus Slytherin"* - Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
> *"Gryffindor versus Slytherin"* - Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix
> *"Gryffindor versus Ravenclaw"* - Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix

With that in mind, it's likely that this isn't the *formal* order, just the order in which Harry perceives them. If the books were told [from Draco's perspective](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BpsBC0RIgAAtO0v.jpg), it's likely that it would have been

> "*Slytherin vs. X*"

---

You might also want to note that in the [PS1 game Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MDg4Ovzpg0&feature=youtu.be&t=213), the announcer and commentator, Lee Jordan is a Gryffindor, is openly biased against teams that aren't Gryffindor and always announces Gryffindor first.

> *It's Gryffindor versus Hufflepuff*
>
> *It's Gryffindor versus ravenclaw*
>
> *It's Gryffindor versus* [deeply antipathetic] *Slytherin*

Comment: Maybe they do it alphabetically? Which would be stupid

Comment: @GordonBennett - The team order on the scoreboard is probably the order in which they get handed to the person hanging the scores

Comment: Are there an examples of two teams being announced that did not include Gryffindor. It would interesting to see if say Slytherin was always announced second.

Comment: @Skooba - There are no other examples of "versus" or "v" or "Vs"

Comment: @Skooba - I'll check "against" when I get back to my books

Comment: "every single example has Gryffindor first" The quote in the question says otherwise. Perhaps that quote is wrong though.

Comment: @GordonBennett Why would ordering them alphabetically be "stupid"?

Comment: @Skooba - "*‘tomorrow’s the first Quidditch match of the season, I believe? Gryffindor against Slytherin, is it not?*" - HPCoS (Lockhart speaking). And that seems to be the only one.

Comment: @JoryGeerts - That quote is from the movie. Note that Slytherin is on the left of the scoreboard